# Spring Security: do UserDetails and UserDetailsService exist in every kind of application which uses Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Ive got a question to Spring Security 3.0.5.

When using Spring Security to secure web application, does a "UserDetails"-Object **always** exist? I mean, does every kind of application (even in other systems like LDAP or X.509 or CAS) using Spring Security also provide a "UserDetails"-Object?

Also, if yes, does every application have then a UserDetailsService?

Well, reading through the Spring Security documentation I dont think so, but I read that the core components always exist (SecurityContextHolder, SecurityContext, Authentication). If so, what sense does the Authentication object have, if it doesnt contain a UserDetails-Object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No.  Different types of authentication mechanisms can use different types of [Authentications](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html).

However, many of the mechanisms do use the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken which has a reference to a UserDetails object.   For example: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter+DaoAuthenticationProvider.  Also UsernamePasswordFilter+LdapAuthenticationProvider.

But: only DaoAuthenticationProviders use a UserDetailsService.

In practice, if you are asking the user for a username/password using a web form you will probably end up using a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and hence a UserDetails.   But you will only use a UserDetailsService if you are using a DaoAuthenticationProvider.

Comment: thank you! but what about SecurityContextHolder, SecurityContext, and Authentication? Those objects must always be used, musnt they?

Comment: SecurityContext has a reference to an Authentication which is just an interface.   UsernamePasswordAuthenticatonToken, which has a reference to a UserDetails, is a type of Authentication but other types are possible (see the Javadoc for Authentication).

Comment: thank you. I know that other types for Authentication are possible. I just wanted to know if every application secured by spring security has a SecurityContextHolder, a SecurityContext and Authentication-Objects (whatever kind of token it will exactly be doesnt matter to me, they all represent the principal, dont they?). These three objects are described as "core"-components, thats why Id like to know it! :-)

Comment: Yes, those are always present but UserDetails/UserDetailsService are not.